# Unable to Attach Database in Azure Data Explorer Cluster

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-explorer

I have ADX (Azure Data Explorer) cluster already created, say Cluster 2. I am trying to attach a database, say Db1, from ADX Cluster, say Cluster 1, with Terraform and Azure Devops.

However, when Terraform executes azurerm_kusto_attached_database_configuration, I get the below error:

What's wrong or missing? What does the error suggests or implies?

```
│ Error: creating/updating Attached Database Configuration (Subscription: "xx"
│ Resource Group Name: "x-rg"
│ Cluster Name: "x"
│ Attached Database Configuration Name: "x"): polling after CreateOrUpdate: Code="Failed" Message="Internal Server Error"
│
│   with module.labs_kusto.azurerm_kusto_attached_database_configuration.this["x"],
│   in resource "azurerm_kusto_attached_database_configuration" "this":
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the `data` block present in `Terraform` to use/refer the existing ADX cluster or any resource in the current code.

*Internal server is only a temporary issue. These can occur as a result of a network issues alternatively; you can look at the cluster settings and retry the deployment. Check the existing cluster permissions and enable the necessary privileges if required.*

By referring to the sample [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.62.0/docs/resources/kusto_attached_database_configuration#argument-reference) template, I modified it as below to achieve your requirement.

```bash
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "caro"
}

resource "azurerm_kusto_cluster" "follower_cluster" {
  name                = "cluster100"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku {
    name     = "Dev(No SLA)_Standard_D11_v2"
    capacity = 1
  }
}

data "azurerm_kusto_cluster" "followed_cluster" {
  name                = "cluster31"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_kusto_database" "followed_database" {
  name                = "blabla"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kusto_cluster.follower_cluster.name
}

resource "azurerm_kusto_database" "example" {
  name                = "examplexxxx"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kusto_cluster.follower_cluster.name
}

resource "azurerm_kusto_attached_database_configuration" "example" {
  name                = "configuration1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kusto_cluster.follower_cluster.name
  cluster_resource_id = data.azurerm_kusto_cluster.followed_cluster.id
  database_name       = azurerm_kusto_database.example.name

  sharing {
    external_tables_to_exclude    = ["ExternalTablex"]
    external_tables_to_include    = ["ExternalTabley"]
    materialized_views_to_exclude = ["MaterializedViewTablex"]
    materialized_views_to_include = ["MaterializedViewTabley"]
    tables_to_exclude             = ["Tablex"]
    tables_to_include             = ["Tabley"]
  }
}
```

*Initialized terraform configuration successfully:*

[image]

*Executed* `terraform plan`:

[image]

*Deployed successfully:*

[image]

[image]